# Clone an ImpactJS ig.Class instance

Tags: javascript, impactjs

In ImpactJS I want to create a copy of an `ig.Animation`. The documentation says that `ig.copy` doesn't work with `ig.Class` based instances. How would I go about creating a copy of an `ig.Animation`?